# Java DateTime is null in Linux

Tags: java, linux, datetime, jodatime

The below code is working in windows but not in Linux

```
public static DateTime now() {
    return new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Singapore"));
}
```

I am using it for created Date and it is working while debugging in local, if I deploy the same in Linux machine it is giving null value
Note: using jodatime

Comment: and what does `DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Singapore")` return?

Comment: Funny. There is no mention in [the documentation of `withZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-) that it may ever return `null`.

Comment: It will return DateTimeZone i.e. Asia/Singapore and we will get DateTime in Singapore time zone

Comment: Are Joda-Time versions the same on both computers? Java versions too?

Comment: I’ve briefly inspected the source code of `DateTime`(Joda-Time version 2.9.9), and I can’t see that `withZone` can return `null`. I would suspect that your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Ole V.V, I checked but dates are not updating, I will debug further, may be issue with linux compatibility .

Comment: If you can use the Java 8 time package instead of Jodatime, I expect you'll get far fewer weird cases like this. It should be pretty easy to convert because it's heavily influenced by Jodatime.